# Share Javascriot object across jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Currently I'm experiencing a little logical problem.
Assume I have an object where I store several mapdata for my tileengine and a jQuery extension which calculates the x and y positions of the clicked tile.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   

        var mapdata = {
            dimensions: {x: 10, y: 10},
            tileSize: 32
        };

        $.fn.getpos = function(type){
            var xpos = $(this)%mapdata.dimensions.y;
            var ypos = Math.floor($(this)/mapdata.dimensions.y);

            else if(type == 'x')
                return xpos;
            else if(type == 'y')
                return ypos;
            else
                return {x: xpos, y:ypos}
        }       

        $('.tile').click(function(){
            console.log($($(this).index('.tile')).getpos());
        });
    });
```

The problem is clear to me. I'm trying to access the mapdata object which is not available within the scope of getpos(). Is there a way I can acomplish this? Otherwise I'd need to pass my mapdata to every extension I'm going to make.

Thank you in advance.
Sincerly,
Thomas

Comment: `mapdata` is in the scope of `$.fn.getpos` when called in the `click` handler. What error are you getting? Perhaps it has to do with treating `$(this)` like a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the getpos() function it inherits the scope at the very same moment, so mapdata as it is defined now should be visible to it.

Try console.log($(this)) inside getpost(). Probably it has value what you don't expect with math operations.

Comment: Thank you. $(this) was an object while I was expecting an integer

Answer (score 1):

When a global variable is set, it is assigned to the window object. Try `window.mapdata`.